# How to install gdb on Solaris 10?

Tags: debugging, unix, solaris

I've installed sun studio, but did not see gdb installed. I see gcc, gcore.  Does it mean gdb is not part of sun studio, and should be installed separately?

Answer (score 1):

Sun Studio debugger is dbx, not gdb. Note that it provides a gdb mode to help people more familiar with the gdb syntax.

Answer (score 1):

we can install gdb in Solaris similar to any other software.but we need to resolve some dependency on other libraries.
https://www.opencsw.org/packages/gdb/.
follow the link to resolve dependencies.
 but better use dbx it is similar to gdb and they are easy to use in solaries.
here are some examples command

step1 :dbx - processid
step2: where (command to check stack trace)
step3:stop methodname or stop sourcefilename:lineno
step4:step (command to step into the function)
step5:next (move to next line)
step7:cont (to continue execution)
step8:run  (to run the command)